Plural or Singular in Zero Case
I have two French speakers helping me. One says a final S is needed. The other says it should NOT be used.

Le bouton de préréglage n'a pas de contrôle.

OR

Le bouton de préréglage n'a pas de contrôles.

ChatGPT and Gemini say the second is right.

Which is right?
Why is there any discrepancy? Canada vs. France? Something else?


Either way is fine, IMHO? The plural feels better though.

Thanks, that works too.

Though I would appreciate some sort of grammar text reference  maybe.

@DanRosenstark What is the context? Can you elaborate on the kind of contrôle(s) this is about?

Sure, this is for the app supported by mididesigner.com and these "controls" are actually "subcontrols". So the button needs subcontrols otherwise this warning shows.  I changed the original text from

Le bouton de préréglage n'a pas de sous-contrôle.

which in English was

Preset knob has no subcontrols


Hi, welcome to fr.WE. Both are grammatically possible: depends how many controls have buttons in the category where the preset button belongs. If they have only one control each, translate pas de contrôle, singular. If they have several controls, translate pas de contrôles, plural. If no such categorization of buttons is relevant, keep it singular.

This question is similar to: Quand faut-il mettre un pluriel après un mot indiquant l'absence d'un élément ? — When to use plural after words that hint at a missing entity?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

My guess is you want to translate this:

The preset button has no control.

I'm not sure about what a "control" means here but whatever it is, contrôle is likely a mistranslation or at best an anglicism.
Contrôle is closer to supervision or inspection in French. What may be a better way to say it is:

Le bouton de préreglage n'a pas de commande(s)1 associée(s).

Whether to use the singular or the plural is a matter of choice.
If this button typically has either zero or one control, you would use the singular, if it might have several controls, either the singular or the plural can be used. See this question.
1 or maybe réglage(s).

This is great but YES it's an aglicism... so all this to say "either is fine?" Thanks, just asking for clarification, I appreciate the answer.

@DanRosenstark No, all this to say "neither is fine" ;-) Otherwise, I would have voted to close the question as a duplicate.

By the way, I just saw that you replied to my comment on your question. I missed it because you didn't use the @xxx prompt. I still don't understand what a control or a subcontrol is but it seems the message is there to warn a designer that they forgot to implement something. A message I would understand assuming sous-contrôle is acceptable in your context would be Bouton de préréglage incomplet, "sous-contrôles" manquants.
